# WinForms DataGridView - databind to an object with a list property (variable number of columns)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have a .NET class I'd like to show in a DataGridView, and the default databinding - setting the DGV's DataSource to the object - produces 90% of my requirements (i.e. it's outputting the public properties correctly and I can add sorting easily).

However, one of the properties I need to bind is a List which contains data which needs to be in separate columns after the other databound items. I'm stuck on how best to implement this.

My class looks something like this:

```
public class BookDetails
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int TotalRating { get; set; }
    public int Occurrence { get; set; }
    public List<int> Rating { get; set; }
}
```

Ideally, I'd be able to expand that Rating property into a number of numeric columns to give an output like this at runtime:

Title |  Total Rating |  Occurrence |  R1 |  R2 |  R3 ... RN

It would also be useful to have Total Rating be calculated as the sum of all the individual ratings, but I'm updating that manually at the moment without issue.

Comment: You are going to have to implement a TypeDescriptor (or maybe TypeConverter) for the type. Quite trivial if you know what to do. Unfortunately a nice example I have written is at work now.

Comment: @leppie - TypeConverter doesn't apply here; actually, ITypedList is probably the easiest; after that - TypeDescriptionProvider (since it won't use ICustomTypeDescriptor for a typed list)

Comment: @leppie - we must be the only two fools I know mad enough to mess with this dark corner of the framework ;p

Comment: (you can also make it read-write, but that gets a little messy because you need to know per-row the length of the list; a bit of a pain...)

Comment: @ Marc Gravell: Heh :)  IIRC, my solution simply inherits from `BindingSource`. Seems the same as your answer.

Comment: @leppie - I'd love to see your `BindingSource` example if you post it tomorrow. If you post it, any chance you could @mention me (so that it appears in my "envelope" list)?

Comment: @Marc Gravell: It's the same thing really, as `BindingSource` inherits from `ITypedList` (and I also had to provide a 'custom' property descriptor). It's virtual in `BindingSource`, so I didn't catch on that it was actually implementing the interface. One limitation is reflecting on type instead of the instance, where your's clearly 'win'. The actual code however exposes a many-to-many relationship in nice matrix, that you literally just hook up to a `DataGridView`, and viola :) Edit: I do have to 'late-bind' that on an actual list however, contradicting what I said earlier. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Like this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class BookDetails
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int TotalRating { get; set; }
    public int Occurrence { get; set; }
    public List<int> Rating { get; set; }
}

class BookList : List<BookDetails>, ITypedList
{

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
    {
        var origProps = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(BookDetails));
        List<PropertyDescriptor> newProps = new List<PropertyDescriptor>(origProps.Count);
        PropertyDescriptor doThisLast = null;
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in origProps)
        {

            if (prop.Name == "Rating") doThisLast = prop;
            else newProps.Add(prop);
        }
        if (doThisLast != null)
        {
            var max = (from book in this
                       let rating = book.Rating
                       where rating != null
                       select (int?)rating.Count).Max() ?? 0;
            if (max > 0)
            {
                // want it nullable to account for jagged arrays
                Type propType = typeof(int?); // could also figure this out from List<T> in
                                              // the general case, but make it nullable
                for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
                {
                    newProps.Add(new ListItemDescriptor(doThisLast, i, propType));
                }
            }
        }
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(newProps.ToArray());
    }

    public string GetListName(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
    {
        return "";
    }
}

class ListItemDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    private static readonly Attribute[] nix = new Attribute[0];
    private readonly PropertyDescriptor tail;
    private readonly Type type;
    private readonly int index;
    public ListItemDescriptor(PropertyDescriptor tail, int index, Type type) : base(tail.Name + "[" + index + "]", nix)
    {
        this.tail = tail;
        this.type = type;
        this.index = index;
    }
    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        IList list = tail.GetValue(component) as IList;
        return (list == null || list.Count <= index) ? null : list[index];
    }
    public override Type PropertyType
    {
        get { return type; }
    }
    public override bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
    public override void ResetValue(object component)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
    public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
    {
        return false;
    }
    public override Type ComponentType
    {
        get { return tail.ComponentType; }
    }
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        var data = new BookList {
            new BookDetails { Title = "abc", TotalRating = 3, Occurrence = 2, Rating = new List<int> {1,2,1}},
            new BookDetails { Title = "def", TotalRating = 3, Occurrence = 2, Rating = null },
            new BookDetails { Title = "ghi", TotalRating = 3, Occurrence = 2, Rating = new List<int> {3, 2}},
            new BookDetails { Title = "jkl", TotalRating = 3, Occurrence = 2, Rating = new List<int>()},
        };
        Application.Run(new Form
        {
            Controls = {
                new DataGridView {
                    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                    DataSource = data
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: (I've also glossed over the whole "list accessor" thing - if you *need* that, it it just a case of following each call through the chain)

Comment: +1 Cool, slightly more complicated than I thought, due to having a variable amount of items in the List :)

Comment: this solution is very interesting. I'm going to have to investigate ITypedList and the whole PropertyDescriptor/TypeDescriptor field. I'm running through the code in the debugger and learning a lot, so many thanks :)

Comment: Excellent solution and it provides a great example to build on. Thanks.

Comment: After all this years... THANK YOU!

Comment: this is a beauty!