# databind a DataGridView to a List of a custom class that has another list as a property

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WinForms DataGridView - databind to an object with a list property (variable number of columns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716092/winforms-datagridview-databind-to-an-object-with-a-list-property-variable-numb)

I have a `DataGridView` that binds to a `List` of a custom class. My custom class is as follows:

```
Class Example
{
    public string Name;
    public double Height;
    public double Length;
    public List<double> ExtraColumns;
}
```

I want my DataGridView to display the properties of my custom class as columns, and an additional column for each item in `List<double> ExtraColumns` property. In other words, I want my grid to look like this when I bind it to a `List<Example>`:

```
      | Name | Height | Length | ExtraColumns[0] | ExtraColumns[1] | ... 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
row1  |      |        |        |                 |                 |
row2  |      |        |        |                 |                 |
row3  |      |        |        |                 |                 |
...   |      |        |        |                 |                 |
```

Is this possible? If so, how would this be implemented?

Comment: This question is identical to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716092/winforms-datagridview-databind-to-an-object-with-a-list-property-variable-numb . Asked an hour ago.

Comment: Wow, you're right, it is. Sorry, I even checked before posting

Comment: No problem  :)  Let's see if anyone can give answers before I do tomorrow at work :)

Comment: This is so similar that I've closed as a duplicate - it should be just a case of changing the property types... (example added on the other thread)