# C# Dynamic extends a object

Tags: c#, reflection, object, dynamic

is it possible to extends a existing object ?

i have the code

```
var record = new
{
    id,
    name
};
```

and have a list of anonymous objects

```
var list = new List<object>(){ object1, object2 };
```

Can i add them later to the object ?
Like something as

```
foreach (var o in list)
{
    record.add(o);
}
```

that i will get this as result

```
var record = new
{
    id,
    name,
    object1,
    object2
};
```

Comment: Is *record* a collection and *object1 object2* are items? Or *object1* is a property of *record*?

Comment: record is a collection, and object1 is a other object that i will add as a new property to record

Comment: @Marco - properties are *named*; items in a list *aren't*...

Comment: I'm not trying to be funny here, actually curious as to what circumstances you would want to do this?

Comment: @Paddy - To use as a return value for a ajax call, i would make JSON of this object and then return it as actionresult but maybe there are other ways to do this

Comment: @Marco - which json serializer? JavaScriptSerializer would allow this quite easily by hooking into the serialization chain, rather than mucking around with objects. Which shows why it is useful to say what you *want to do*, rather than *how you are trying it*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no. At least, not with anonymous types. There are two approaches here; `dynamic` might give you what you want, but is fiddly for combining. Other than that, a basic property bag - even simply `Dictionary<string,object>` would do. The only difference being that:

```
obj.id
```

becomes

```
obj["id"]
```

There is a more fundamental problem, though, in trying to combine a *list* (each of which is largely anonymous) with *properties* in a single step. You *can* do this [for data-binding purpose via custom property models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716092/winforms-datagridview-databind-to-an-object-with-a-list-property-variable-numb/4717268#4717268), but it is... tricky.

Comment: The ViewState and the Session objects in asp.net are classic examples of the property bag approach. Anything can go in, anything can come out, and there's no need for convoluted syntax.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a class Extension. It is not possible to add new methods in the runtime, but you can do something like this:

```
public class OneClass
{
  private List<object> items;
  public List<object> Items { get { return items; } }
  public void AddOne(object item)
  {
    items.Add(item);
  }
}
```

if you want to extend this class behavior, you can write an extension class. Like this:

```
public static class OneClassExtensions
{
  public void AddMany(this OneClass self, params object[] items)
  {
    foreach(object item in items)
    {
      self.Items.Add(item);
    }
  }
}
```

This way you can call this extension method from your OneClass objects:

```
OneClass obj = new OneClass();
obj.AddOne("hello");
obj.AddMany("Hello", "world"); // Extension method
```

There are some rules to follow:

1. The extension class must have the `static' modifier
2. you need to put the `this' prefix before the first argument. This argument would be the object itself.
3. In order to use this extension class in your code, you must use the namespace that contains that extension class, like `using Some.Namespace.That.Has.An.Extension' in every .cs file where you want to use extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone runs into this question in the future, I have recently published a library to do exactly this. You can find it on nuget.org - it's called (unsurprisingly) ObjectExtend.

You can install it by grabbing it from [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/objectextend/) or via your favourite package manager. You can also check out the [source code](https://github.com/rophuine/objectextend), a [brief introduction](http://www.nerdhold.com/coder/2018/04/09/object-extend-linqpad/), or a [detailed overview of how it works](http://www.nerdhold.com/coder/2018/04/11/how-csharp-object-extend-works/).

The short version is - install the package, make sure you import the namespace with `using Rophuine.LINQPad.ObjectExtend;`, and now you should be able to call `.Extend` on your objects.

A caveat: this is a great technique for exploratory coding, but I recommend against it for anything which will be maintained or go to production.

Answer (score 0):

Since .net4 you could use ExpandoObject to do stuff like that.

For example:

```
        var objs = new List<ExpandoObject>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            dynamic eObj = new ExpandoObject();
            eObj.Property = i;
            objs.Add(eObj);
        }

        foreach (dynamic obj in objs)
        {
            obj.Property2 = "bubuValue" + obj.Property;
            obj.Property3 = "bubuValue" + obj.Property2;
        }

        foreach (dynamic obj in objs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Property3);
        }
```