# WinForms DataGridView - databind object with List property (variable number of columns) AND that List property has List property too

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

My question starts with [Marc Gravels's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716092/winforms-datagridview-databind-to-an-object-with-a-list-property-variable-numb/4717268#4717268) regarding WinForms DataGridView - databind object with List property (variable number of columns).

First, my structures are as such:

```
    public class BookTypeAndRating {
     public string BookType { get; set; }
     public List<int> Rating { get; set; }
 } 

    public class BookDetails {
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public List<BookTypeAndRating> BookTypeRating { get; set; } 
}
```

I'd like my outoput to look like this:
Title | BookType1 | BookType2 | BookType3 ... BookTypeN

And below is an example of my data table:

```
Title     | "Adventure" | "Sci-Fi"  | "Mystery" | "Tech"
"Title_1" |     1       |    4      |     8     |    4
"Title_2" |     2       |    4      |     1     |    2
"Title_3" |     3       |    4      |     2     |    1
"Title_4" |     5       |    4      |     2     |    5
```

I understand the basics of databinding and Marc's example.  My problems are:

1. How to databind the BookType property to each column?
2. Users will be manipulating the data table - add/delete/update.  Any suggestions would help.
3. Rating is a set of values (1 .. 50) and I want to have this in a comboBox within the columns - how do I add these items to a column and still databind to this object.