# Add property at run-time

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview, binding

I have a `List<Data>` where:

```
class Data
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and I use this list as the `ItemsSource` of a `ListView`. 

The `View` of my `ListView` is a `GridView` with one `GridViewColumn` (iniltially) and I bind the property `Data.Name` using the `DisplayMemberBinding` of my `GridViewColumn`.

At run-time **may** happen that I add a new `GridViewColumn` to my `GridView`, so i need to bind a **new** property of `Data` to this new column.

How can I do this?

Comment: What new property would you bind to? Where would the data come from? There *are* ways to do this, involving custom PropertyDescriptor etc - but to advice on "how", more context is required.

Comment: @MarcGravell For example the new property `public string Surname{ get; set; }`. The data could come from a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't add "regular" properties at runtime - frankly, for what you describe might want to bind to a DataTable, and map the data in. You *can* do this at runtime but it is pretty complex. DataTable has a full implementation already.

Comment: Maybe it's complicated, but i need it. Can i find some references/examples somewhere?

Comment: @Nick I have some here on SO: what you are mainly looking for is ITypedList - the following is winforms, but should work in wpf too:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716092/winforms-datagridview-databind-to-an-object-with-a-list-property-variable-num

Answer (score 1):

edit: it looks like I misunderstood the question.  If you're trying to add a property to the `Data` class, then I think you're out of luck.  If you already have the property and simply want to bind that existing property to the `GridView`, then the code below should help.

Assuming the `DataContext` of the GridView is already set, you can use something similar to the example at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.columns.aspx):

```
GridViewColumn gvc = new GridViewColumn();
gvc.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Surname");
gvc.Header = "Surname";
gvc.Width = 100;
myGridView.Columns.Add(gvc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with adding actual property to the data instance is rather complicated,

but maybe one of these solutions will be sufficient

You can use dynamics (more details here: [dynamics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx))

```
        dynamic dynamicData = new ExpandoObject();
        dynamicData.Name = "Name";
        dynamicData.Surname = "SomeSurname";
```

If you can rebuild collection of data items you can use anonymous types (more details here [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx))

```
        var data = new Data();
        string newPropertyName = "Surname";
        var data2 = new { Name = data.Name, newPropertyName = "SomeString" };
```

Unless you are using DataTemplates to bind to contrete type of Data.