# Is it possible to have a DataGridView without connecting to a Database?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to have a Windows DataGridView that displays data from a C# structure. Does anyone know of any examples for me to learn from? All the examples on Internet are using a SQL or Oracle or Access database.  However, I just need to have a C# table kind of structure with few rows and few columns from which to populate my DataGridView.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can bind it to IEnumerable items such as lists etc

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0wfd4yz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

[WinForms DataGridView - databind to an object with a list property (variable number of columns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716092/winforms-datagridview-databind-to-an-object-with-a-list-property-variable-num)

A couple of links

Answer (score 1):

DataGridViews can use a locally stored BindingList (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as the DataSource.

Answer (score 1):

if my understanding of your question.

Yes , this is possible with datatable. Datable rows iterate one by one and directly assign to datagridview.

Here I post one example :

```
            foreach (DataRow rows in dt.Rows)
            {
                int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = rows[0].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = rows[1].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = rows[2].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = rows[3].ToString();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

As other have pointed out, you can either work in unbound, or bound fashion with the DataGridView (DGV).

My preference is to always use bound mode, as this methods allows you to "ignore" the DGV internals (most of the time), and you can then simply change the underlying data to which the grid is bound, and let the Data Binding mechanism of Windows Forms do its job.

When I say that you can igbnore the DGV internals, what I mean is that you don't have to start handling DGV events to set or get your data in and out of it. You jet let Data Binding do it.

As mentioned by others, you can bind a DGV to pretty much anything that implements IEnumerable, so if you have a list of custom objects, the DGV will take that as its datasource.

I hope you have good success with this.

Cheers